# No default engine was specified and no extension was provided - error in expressjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using expressjs only for backend. I want to store data into mongodb using express.All my view part is done in zend. I do not need view in express. I am trying to write a proto for this. Can someone tell me how do i disable view in expressjs. I just want to serve the request with json data.

I am getting this error when i send a request and route it to index.js.
This is how i redirected it to index.js

```
app.get("/index",function(req,res){
console.log("route to index");
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't specify an engine (app.engine in express 4x) and just return your json:

```
app.get('/index', function (req, res) {
  ....
  ....
  res.json(json_data);
});
```

This will not route to index.js. The "/index" is merely a route and if the request path matches it, it will run the contents of the callback. If you need the contents of index.js, you're going to need to require it. Ex: `var code = require('./index');`

My app.js:

```
var express =require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/index",function(req,res){
  var json_data = {"name":"amita","pass":"12345"};
  res.json(json_data);
})

app.listen(3000);
console.log("listening to port 3000");
```

Browsing to localhost:3000/index, I see {"name":"amita","pass":"12345"}

Comment: I did. For now i gave some static json data. This is what i added to app.js                                                             app.get("/index",function(req,res){
json_data = {"name":"amita","pass":"12345"};                                          
res.json(json_data);
})    I am getting 404

Comment: It's working for me when I go to localhost:3000/index with the app.js I updated in my response. Are you browsing to the correct url? I only get a 404 when I browse to a route that doesn't exist.